# how can I change the SSAS instance in SSMS? (tabular mode instance vs. multidimensional mode instance)

Tags: installation, ssas, ssms

I have two installations of SSAS in SQL Server 2014:

- Default instance (tabular mode SSAS) service name:
  MSSQLServerOLAPService
- Second instance (multidimensional mode SSAS) service name: MSOLAP$InstanceName

I don't need the default instance since it's tabular mode. I think changing the server mode of an existing SSAS instance ([like seen here](http://cathydumas.com/2012/04/23/changing-an-analysis-services-instance-to-tabular-mode/)) is not the best way since this is not suported by MS.... So I tried to install a second instance. But I don't find an option in SSMS how to start the second instance instead of the default instance. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Connected to server name `DOMAIN\MSSQLSERVEROLAP` instead of just `DOMAIN`.